# Кракозябры в выводе psql

Tags: sql, postgresql, psql

Я пытаюсь загрузить данные в существующую postgres базу данных с помощью DataGrip от JetBrains. У меня есть sql файл, который я загружаю через диалог Restore (клик правой кнопкой мыши на БД, пункт Restore).

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В этом диалоговом окне я выбираю вкладку psql, после чего нажимаю Run. Проблема в том, что в процессе этого импорта я получаю множество ошибок, но сами сообщения об ошибках выводятся со сбитой кодировкой. Что-то наподобие этого:

```
ПОДРОБНОСТИ:  РљР»СЋС‡ "(id)=(15760)" СѓР¶Рµ СЃСѓС‰РµСЃС‚РІСѓРµС‚.
psql:C:/Users/MyUser/Desktop/script.sql:58395: РћРЁР�Р‘РљРђ:  РїРѕРІС‚РѕСЂСЏСЋС‰РµРµСЃСЏ Р·РЅР°С‡РµРЅРёРµ РєР»СЋС‡Р° РЅР°СЂСѓС€Р°РµС‚ РѕРіСЂР°РЅРёС‡РµРЅРёРµ СѓРЅРёРєР°Р»СЊРЅРѕСЃС‚Рё "pk_events"
ПОДРОБНОСТИ:  РљР»СЋС‡ "(id)=(15771)" СѓР¶Рµ СЃСѓС‰РµСЃС‚РІСѓРµС‚.
```

Проблема, как я подозреваю, кроется не в настройках DataGrip, а в настройках postgres, в частности, утилиты psql. Может кто-то знает, как поправить кодировку?

Операционная система Windows 10, версия postgres 12.2

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте следующее.

1.Запустить cmd.exe, нажать мышью в правом левом верхнем углу окна, там Свойства - Шрифт - выбрать Lucida Console. Нажать ОК.

2. Выполнить команду:
   chcp 1251
   В ответ выведет:
   Текущая кодовая страница: 1251
3. Запустить psql;

psql -d ВАШАБАЗА -U ВАШлогин

Выполнить:
set client_encoding='win1251';

Он выведет:
SET

И все.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но к сожалению не сработало(